# How to download files from adf.ly to a remote server?

Tags: remote-server, download

I am trying to download a file to a remote server from the website `adf.ly`, but when I try wget it downloads the website html code. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start the download on your own computer (and watch the ad and everything). Then once its downloading the file, you should be able to get the URL where its downloading from by looking at your "Downloads" section (in Chrome, for example). Copy that URL and use it to download from the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are wget'ing the link to the actual file, not the ad.fly link. Ad.fly has it setup this way to force you to watch their ads.

Comment: I don't know what the link to the file is though, just the adf.ly link to the file I need :/

Comment: And I can't just watch through the ad because I need to download the file to the remote server, not a local drive